# Ionic 5 UI glich when updated to latest chrome

Tags: user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic5

My Ionic 5 app suddenly breaks the UI after updating the chrome version in my android to the latest version (92.0.4515.159). so I tried to import the ionic conference app to check if the glitch still occurs and yet the glitching was still there.

Here are the screenshots

[image: Sidebar menu]

[image: Ion tab bar not showing]

Comment: you should report this bug to ionic github repo.

Comment: Please include relevant code and format the photos so that they appear here on this page without having to click links